# Is it considered okay (standards-wise) to mix HTML 4 and HTML 5?

Tags: html, seo, web-standards, html4

I'm basically wondering wether or not it's considered okay (standards wise) to mix HTML 4 and HTML 5.

For instance, what if I have an HTML 4 `body` element with an HTML5 `audio` tag in it. I know it works and renders properly, but is it okay standards-wise, and will my SEO value be penalized by it?

**Edit**
As a lot of posts pointed out, HTML 5 has a body element too. Apparently, only a few elements are deprecated and marked as obsolete every time a new HTML standard arrives. Please don't downvote my question now, since I think there are others misunderstanding this too. That way, I don't have to delete it.

Comment: What is the difference between an HTML 4 `body` element and an HTML 5 `body` element?

Comment: the elements you specified are both HTML 5, hence you aren't mixing anything. Can you give a better example of perhaps what issue you're facing? Using HTML 4 elements is safe in HTML 5, since new elements are introduced and only a few deprecated ones were dropped.

Comment: @ericosg, thanks. Your answer is the best. Can you make it as a real answer, and I will mark it as accepted?

Comment: Why does this get voted down? I think it'll help others with the same issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements you specified are both HTML 5, hence you aren't mixing anything.

(If you give a better example of perhaps what issue you're facing, or which elements you are thinking of, perhaps we can elaborate.)

Using HTML 4 elements is safe in HTML 5, since new elements are introduced and only a few deprecated ones were dropped.

Answer (score -1):

It is okay, there is nothing wrong in mixing. However you need to provide fallback for html5 elements that aren't supported in older browsers. You might need to include some libraries like [Modernizer](http://www.modernizr.com/) and [shiv](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/) to make things seamless.